# align divs side by side and center

Tags: html, css

i have 3 divs. 1 is container and i want those other two aligned in center side by side width same width. but it looks like this [image]

i want it to be aligned like this [image]

here are my codes:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="bottom-content">
   <div id="left-desc">

   </div>
   <div id="description-space">

   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#bottom-content{
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
}
#left-desc{
    border: 1px solid orane;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#description-space{
    border: 1px solid orange;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: you need to add `box-sizing:border-box` to your inner divs, the width adds the padding and border to it so your divs are over 50% which is why they aren't next to each other

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YZ3Kg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your floating styles and display the `<div>` elements as table/table-cells.

A `table` element won't fill the width of its container, so also give it `width:100%` (or whatever width you desire). You should change the `box-sizing` property of your container to have the width include the border.

```
#bottom-content{
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;

}
#left-desc{
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    display:table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#description-space{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5yDzG/2/)

Comment: Its better to use `box-sizing` here

Comment: @Mr.Alien I was editing, made some changes. Also I assumed from the question that the heights of either element should match the height of the container, which is why I chose the `display:table-cell` approach.

Comment: thank man it helped. this did better because i have another div over this. thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
#bottom-content{
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
}
#left-desc, #description-space { /* add this block */
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 400px; /* for demonstration purposes */
}
#left-desc{
    border: 1px solid orane;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#description-space{
    border: 1px solid orange;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N2qtc/)